# No Linker option in Project Properties

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to change the linker options in my project, but after looking at every location it is apparently meant to be located at, I cannot find it anywhere.

Here is a screenshot of where I believe it is meant to be:
[image]

As can be seen, there is apparently no mention of the linker. Anyone got any ideas on this?

Comment: This usually happens when you have a static library and not a dynamic one. Some "linker" options are still hidden in the "Librarian" option.

Comment: There are no linker options in a static library, which is exactly what you have here. The lack of a "Linker" section, and the presence of the "Librarian" section, are best-evidence of that. If you thought you were building a DLL, think again; you weren't.

Answer (score 2):

Reiterating what the helpful comments say:

> This usually happens when you have a static library and not a dynamic one. Some "linker" options are still hidden in the "Librarian" option.

<sup>- [@Hayt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290155/c-visual-studio-no-linker-option-in-project-properties#comment65914081_39290155)</sup>

> There are no linker options in a static library, which is exactly what you have here. The lack of a "Linker" section, and the presence of the "Librarian" section, are best-evidence of that. If you thought you were building a DLL, think again; you weren't.

<sup>- [@WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290155/c-visual-studio-no-linker-option-in-project-properties#comment65914130_39290155)</sup>